# Numpy array error setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i tryed to use multilist to hold scraped data from html

but after 50.000 list append i got memory error

So i decided to change lists to numpy array

```
SapList= []
ListAll  =  np.array([])

def eachshop(): #filling each list for each shop data
    global ListAll
    SapList.append(RowNum)
    SapList.extend([sap]) # here can be from one to 10 values in one list["sap1","sap2","sap3",...,"sap10"]
    SapList.extend([[strLink,ProdName],ProdCode,ProdH,NewPrice, OldPrice,[FileName+'#Komp!A1',KompPrice],[FileName+'#Sav!A1','Sav']])
    SapList.extend([ss]) # here can be from null to 80 sublist with 3 values [["id1", "link", "address"],["id80", "link", "address"]]


    ListAll = np.append(np.array(SapList))
```

So then i do `print(ListAll)` i got exception `C:\Python36\scrap.py, LINE 307 "ListAll = np.append(np.array(SapList))"): setting an array element with a sequence`

now for speed up i using pool.map

```
def makePool(cP, func, iters):
    try:

        pool = ThreadPool(cP)
        #perebiraem Url
        pool.map_async(func,enumerate(iters, start=2)).get(99999)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    except:
        print('Pool Error')
        raise
    finally:
        pool.terminate()
```

So how to use numpy array in my example and reduce memory usage and speedup I\O operation using Numpy?

Comment: If you want an array you can append rows to, you need a 2D array, not a 1D array.

Comment: Also what is that `ListAll = np.append(np.array(SapList))` supposed to be doing? It’s obviously not going to append anything to `ListAll`, it’s going to call `append` on nothing but the temp array created from `SapList`, then store the result in `ListAll`, replacing whatever used to be there. I’m pretty sure that’s not what you want, but I’m not sure what you _do_ want, so I can’t tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I thought `ListAll = np.append(np.array(SapList))` is same as `ListAll.append([SapList])`

Comment: No, they're not even remotely the same. The latter calls an `append` method on `ListAll`. The former calls an `append` function on the `np` module, doesn't even pass `ListAll` to it, and then just assigns the result to `ListAll`.

Comment: Consider dumping out the results every 10k instead of waiting for it to run out of memory at 50k entries.

Comment: Please show working example. As i need save result in excel with xlsxwriter, but it cant append to same file

Comment: How much memory does your python process use before it breaks? Are you sure you want to dump GBs of data into a single excel sheet?

Comment: about 8GB eats. Yes i want only in excel, as array only have 70.000-100.000 rows.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I feel if a python script can't handle the memory your data uses all at once, excel might have an even bigger problem...

Comment: everything good. excel file only 60mb. Something bad with holding long list in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hpaulj pointed out already, `numpy` arrays will not help here, since you don't have consistent data sizes.

As Spinor8 suggested, dump out data in between instead:

```
AllList = []
limit = 10000
counter = 0
while not finished:
    if counter >= limit:
        print AllList
        AllList = []
    item = CreateYourList(...)
    AllList.append(item)
    counter += 1
```

**Edit**: Since your question is specifically asking about numpy and you even opened a bounty: numpy is *not* going to help you here, and here is why:

- For using numpy efficiently, you have to know the array size at the time of array creation. `numpy.array.append()` doesn't actually append anything, but creates a *new* array, which is a huge overhead with large arrays.
- Numpy arrays work best if all items have the same number of elements. Specifically, you can think of a numpy array like a matrix: all rows have the same number of columns.
- You could create a numpy array based on the largest element in your data stream, but this would mean you allocate memory that you don't need (array elements that will never be filled). This will clearly not solve your memory problem.

So IMHO, your only way to solve this is to break your stream into chunks that your memory can handle, and stitch it together afterwards. Maybe write it to a (temporary) file and append to it?

Comment: columns number always the same. only differs info in this columns and rows count. It is products scraping from website

Comment: Your data is way more complex than a simple matrix, its multidimensional, and it's not always the same (judged by your code and your comments)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to make an array from a list that contains a number and lists.  Something like:

```
In [6]: np.array([1, [1,2],[3,4]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-812a9ccb6ca0> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array([1, [1,2],[3,4]])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

It does work if all elements of lists

```
In [7]: np.array([[1], [1,2],[3,4,5]])
Out[7]: array([list([1]), list([1, 2]), list([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

But if they vary in length the result is an object array, not a 2d numeric array.  Such an object dtype array is very much like a list of lists, containing pointers to lists elsewhere in memory.

A multidimensional numeric array can use less memory than a list of lists, but it isn't going to help if you need to make the lists first.  And it does not help at all if the sublists vary in size.

Oh, and stay away from `np.append`.  It's **evil**.  Plus you misused it!

Comment: Yep sublist always vary sized